# Didn't get any response from messenger

Tags: node.js, facebook, bots, webhooks, messenger

Following Facebook tutorial on **how to setup a messenger bot** - setup my webhook using ngrok. Everything goes well on local testing, but still not getting any response from the bot when sending messages to it .

**ngrok**
https://ngrok.com/

**facebook tutorial** 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/quick-start/

used this command to test my bot locally and it got success

curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":43674671559,"time":1460620433256,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":123456789},"recipient":{"id":987654321},"timestamp":1460620433123,"message":{"mid":"mid.1460620432888:f8e3412003d2d1cd93","seq":12604,"text":"Testing Chat Bot .."}}]}]}' https://www.YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL_HERE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was on the roles page setting as my messenger was on development mode so It needed to have only Admin, Developer, Testers to test it ,
So I've assigned to it a developer and web hook started receiving events .